# Query table by a value in the second dimension of a two dimensional array column

Tags: postgresql

**WHAT I HAVE**

I have a table with the following definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Highlights"
(
  id uuid,
  chunks numeric[][]
)
```

**WHAT I NEED TO DO**

I need to query the data in the table using the following predicate:

```sql
... WHERE id = 'some uuid' and chunks[????????][1] > 10 chunks[????????][3] < 20
```

What should I put instead of `[????????]` in order to scan **all items** in the first dimension of the array?

**Notes**

I'm not entirely sure that `chunks[][1]` even close to something I need.

All I need is to test a row, whether its `chunks` column contains a two dimensional array, that has in any of its tuples some specific values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be there's better alternative, but this might do - you just go over first dimension of each array and testing your condition:

```
select *
from highlights as h
where
    exists (
        select
        from generate_series(1, array_length(h.chunks, 1)) as tt(i)
        where
            -- your condition goes here
            h.chunks[tt.i][1] > 10 and h.chunks[tt.i][3] < 20
    )
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ef8f40827fe88736519efa33eb1dbe3a)

**update** as @arie-r pointed out, it'd be better to use [`generate_subscripts`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS) function:

```
select *
from highlights as h
where
    exists (
        select *
        from generate_subscripts(h.chunks, 1) as tt(i)
        where
            h.chunks[tt.i][3] = 6
    )
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3d250647fd5d713fc4eb555ee34c7557)

Comment: I would use `generate_subscripts(h.chunks, 1)`, but otherwise, it can be accepted as an answer. Can indexes improve the performance here? Any suggestions?

Comment: @ArieR great suggestion. Honestly, I'm not sure if indexes can really improve performance